# RAND returns suplicates and sometimes no values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a quiz using mysql and php
I want to fetch questions randomly from the database 
I have a truble with rand function 
sometimes it seturns no value and returns also duplications 
I tried to find a solution on the net but couldn't make it 
this is the part of code that generate the problem

```
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database"); 
$req="SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `qst_s`
WHERE `id_qst` = ROUND( RAND()*49 ) + 1 AND `level` = '1'  LIMIT 40";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$req);
$question=$result->fetch_assoc();
```

I have 50 questions in my database level 1 by the way

Comment: `"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM \`qst_s\`
WHERE \`level\` = '1' ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 40";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of selecting random rows from the MySQL database is to use "ORDER BY RAND()" clause in the query.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

The problem with this method is that it is very slow. The reason for it being so slow is that MySQL creates a temporary table with all the result rows and assigns each one of them a random sorting index. The results are then sorted and returned.

Your query would look like this:

```
$req="SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `qst_s`
WHERE `level` = '1'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 40";
```

Comment: thnk you fo feedback I tried that the code looks like this 
            $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","aeel"); 
            $req="SELECT DISTINCT * 
            FROM `qst_s`
            WHERE `level` = '1'  LIMIT ORDERBY RAND() LIMIT 40";
 
            $resultat=mysqli_query($link,$req);
     $question=$result->fetch_assoc();
but it generated an error

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: @ImadArifi - It's not `ORDERBY`, it's `ORDER BY` and remove the first `LIMIT` before your `ORDER BY`. But your error indicates that the connection wasn't made and that `$link` is null.